Apex Class - Prefill LInk -
I am creating an Apex Class to interact with Jotform API and use it in a flow. We want to create the form and populate it with data and also get the Prefill Link to use in the flow (to update the object candidate field Jotform_Talent_Prefill_Link_c) and then send it in the email as well. However, I am getting the SAME Prefill ID every time.
public with sharing class JotformServiceTestV2 {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Send Jotform Data' description='Send data to Jotform and get the prefill link')
    public static List<PrefillLinkOutput> sendJotformData(List<PrefillLinkInput> requestDataList) {
        List<PrefillLinkOutput> results = new List<PrefillLinkOutput>();
        for (PrefillLinkInput requestData : requestDataList) {
            String prefillLink = sendJotformDataSync(requestData);
            results.add(new PrefillLinkOutput(prefillLink));
        }
        return results;
    }

    public class PrefillLinkInput {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String candidateName;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String caseHandledBy;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String certificationProgram;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String correctiveActionPlan;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String dateOfIncident;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String descriptionOfIncident;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String disciplinaryAction;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String followupDate;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String followupMethod;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String programEnrollmentDate;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String reasonForDisciplinaryAction;
    }

    public class PrefillLinkOutput {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String prefillLink;

        public PrefillLinkOutput(String prefillLink) {
            this.prefillLink = prefillLink;
        }
    }

    private static final String API_KEY = '';
    private static final String BASE_URL = '';
    private static final String FORM_ID = '';
    private static final String ACCOUNT_ID = '';

    private static String sendJotformDataSync(PrefillLinkInput requestData) {
        try {
            String prefillId = createEmptyPrefillConfiguration();
            Map<String, String> questionKeys = getQuestionKeys();
            Map<String, Object> bodyMap = new Map<String, Object>();
            
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('candidateName'), requestData.candidateName);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('caseHandledBy'), requestData.caseHandledBy);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('certificationProgram'), requestData.certificationProgram);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('correctiveActionPlan'), requestData.correctiveActionPlan);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('dateOfIncident'), requestData.dateOfIncident);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('descriptionOfIncident'), requestData.descriptionOfIncident);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('disciplinaryAction'), requestData.disciplinaryAction);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('followupDate'), requestData.followupDate);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('followupMethod'), requestData.followupMethod);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('programEnrollmentDate'), requestData.programEnrollmentDate);
            addToMapIfNotNull(bodyMap, questionKeys.get('reasonForDisciplinaryAction'), requestData.reasonForDisciplinaryAction);

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(BASE_URL + '/API/form/' + FORM_ID + '/prefills/' + prefillId + '?apiKey=' + API_KEY);
            req.setMethod('PUT');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setBody(JSON.serialize(bodyMap));

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

            if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                return BASE_URL + '/form/' + FORM_ID + '/prefill/' + prefillId;
            } else {
                throw new CalloutException('Error with status code: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' and body: ' + res.getBody());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            throw new CalloutException('Failed to send Jotform data: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static String createEmptyPrefillConfiguration() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(BASE_URL + '/API/form/' + FORM_ID + '/prefills?apiKey=' + API_KEY);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody('{"provider":"salesforceV2","account_id":"' + ACCOUNT_ID + '","configuration":{"list":"' + ACCOUNT_ID + '"}}');

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            Map<String, Object> contentMap = (Map<String, Object>) responseMap.get('content');
            return (String) contentMap.get('id');
        } else {
            throw new CalloutException('Error creating empty prefill configuration: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + res.getBody());
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getQuestionKeys() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(BASE_URL + '/API/form/' + FORM_ID + '/questions?apiKey=' + API_KEY);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            Map<String, Object> contentMap = (Map<String, Object>) responseMap.get('content');
            Map<String, String> questionKeys = new Map<String, String>();
            for (String key : contentMap.keySet()) {
                Map<String, Object> content = (Map<String, Object>) contentMap.get(key);
                questionKeys.put((String) content.get('text'), (String) content.get('name'));
            }
            return questionKeys;
        } else {
            throw new CalloutException('Error fetching question keys: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + res.getBody());
        }
    }

    private static void addToMapIfNotNull(Map<String, Object> theMap, String key, Object value) {
        if (key != null && value != null) {
            theMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    public class CalloutException extends Exception {}
}

